# Wildfly 14 JNDI http-remoting request to port 8080 not working with ear and more than 61 jars in it

Tags: jar, jboss, wildfly, jndi, ear

We are currently migrating from JBoss AS 7 to Wildfly 14. Now we have the strange behavior that our JNDI http-remtoing requests do not work if we have more than 61 jars in our ear (Needed for Authetification and Permissions-Lookup). We can remove any jar (that do not have any dependencies to other artifacts) and if we start our Wildfly it works. It just has to be less than 61 jars in our ear-File (I'm referencing to the modules in the ear, not the libs). No Error-Message on Wildfly appears, it seams that the request never arrives to wildfly, but the client still waits. I tried also with different ports, but nothing.

Our code is compiled with Maven src 1.6 to target 1.7. Running JRE on Wildfly is 1.8.

Do anyone has experienced same problems with migrating from JBoss AS 7 to Wildfly?

We also tried with a older version of Wildfly (Wildfly 11) and had the same Problem. I really don't want to have to debug the server, so if somebody has a clue, experienced the same or any idea why this behaviour can behave, then please help me :-)

At the moment we are trying to set up the Wildfly in Standalone-Mode, target is to let it run in Domain-Mode as a Cluster-Server. When this will work, we want to update our project first to Java 8 and after that to a higher version like Java 10 or 11.

This is the Test-Lookup and -Call that I fire

```
    final Hashtable<String, String> jndiProperties = new Hashtable<>();


    //jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user-name");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "xxxxxxxxxxx");
    jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    final Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

    final DistServer ds = (DistServer) ctx.lookup(
            "ejb:our-server/distribution-server/DistServerBean!com.someenterprise.common.DistServer");

    System.out.println("Calling canIAccess returns " + ds.canIAccess());
```

Comment: Nobody has an idea?

Comment: OK now we discovered that when you create an empty deployment additional to our deployed ear and then you disable it an re-enable it, the jdni call works for one time. disable and re-enable the empty deployment e second time and then it works every time. Very strange behavior ...